# Strange bug when subclassing UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

When I subclass UISplitViewController and set it's viewControllers property everything is fine. However once I add this single line to my subclass the master view controller grows to the size of a detail view and overlaps my detail view.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) MMMasterViewController* masterViewController;
```

Anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I changed the name of my property and it worked.

Why?

It most likely was overriding a private property of UISplitViewController.

Answer (score 1):

The private property name for the details view seems to be `detailViewController`. I used that name and my details view moved under the master view.

It seems best to avoid using either of these property names in a subclass.